# Error net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED

Tags: javascript, connection, peer

I developed a communication program using peer the following script.js

```
$(function(){
  var messages = [];
  var peer_id, name, conn;
  var messages_template = Handlebars.compile($('#messages-template').html());
  var peer = new Peer({
    host: '187.84.228.139',
    port: 9000,
    path: '/peerjs',
    debug: 3,
    config: {'iceServers': [
    { url: 'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302' },
    { url: 'turn:numb.viagenie.ca',
      credential: 'muazkh', username: 'webrtc@live.com' }
    ]}
  });
  peer.on('open', function(){
    $('#id').text(peer.id);
  });
})
```

But at the moment of picking up the id the following messages occur:

```
Failed to load 187.84.228.139:9000/peerjs/peerjs/id?ts=15204245707800.6806042256269524 resource: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED
peer.js:1476 PeerJS:  ERROR Error retrieving ID undefined
peer.js:1476 PeerJS:  ERROR Aborting!
peer.js:1476 PeerJS:  ERROR Error: Could not get an ID from the server.
peer.js:1476 PeerJS:  ERROR Error retrieving ID ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …}
peer.js:1476 PeerJS:  ERROR Aborting!
peer.js:1476 PeerJS:  ERROR Error: Could not get an ID from the server.
```

What is happening? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a program "ending the deadline"?

Comment: Sorry. English is not my language. It means I need finish this programm urgently.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.